# Why is Turing completeness right?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, history

I am using a digital computer to write this message. Such a machine has a property which, if you think about it, is actually quite remarkable: It is *one machine* which, if programmed appropriately, can perform *any possible computation*.

Of course, calculating machines of one kind or another go back to antiquity. People have built machines which for performing addition and subtraction (e.g., an abacus), multiplication and division (e.g., the slide rule), and more domain-specific machines such as calculators for the positions of the planets.

The striking thing about a computer is that it can perform *any* computation. Any computation at all. And all without having to rewire the machine. Today everybody takes this idea for granted, but if you stop and think about it, it's kind of amazing that such a device is possible.

I have two actual *questions*:

1. When did mankind figure out that such a machine was possible? Has there ever been any serious *doubt* about whether it can be done? When was this settled? (In particular, was it settled before or after the first actual implementation?)
2. How did mathematicians *prove* that a Turing-complete machine really can compute everything?

That second one is fiddly. Every formalism seems to have some things that *cannot* be computed. Currently "computable function" is *defined as* "anything a Turing-machine can compute". But how do we know there isn't some slightly more powerful machine that can compute more stuff? How do we know that Turing-machines are the correct abstraction?

Comment: Computers (and their theoretical models, like Turing machines) CANNOT compute everything. Check out for example the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Answer to second question: we don't prove this; it's a matter of definition; it turns out what we think intuitively of "computable" is computable by Turing machines (or anything equivalent). This claim is known as [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church-Turing_thesis).

Comment: [What would it mean to disprove Church-Turing thesis?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/88/1037)

Comment: Machines like your PC that have finite memory are not Turing equivalent.  Turing machines have an unbounded tape which means that the longer a computation continues, the more memory they can potentially use. PCs cannot perform computations that take finite time but that require more storage than they have available.

Comment: @MikeSamuel this is a pedantic distinction and akin to saying "there is a finite number of particles in the universe, thus everything is finite state". It is a true statement, but not a useful one. It is seldom useful to model a real-world computer as a finite state machine.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev, It's not a pedantic distinction.  Computations that take O(n^3) time and O(n) memory can be performed on either a Turing machine or a PC (Von Neumann machine) for reasonable values of n, but ones that require O(n^3) time and memory cannot be performed on a PC for similar values of n.  If you want an example of pedantic : finite particles do not imply finite state.  The cardinality of the state space of a single particle single real-dimension universe is infinite since that particle can be placed in an infinite number of distinct positions along that single dimension.

Comment: @kol: There wouldn't be much point in defining the term "computable function" if _every_ function were computable, now would there?

Comment: Computers can use external, unbounded storage space just fine.

Comment: "The striking thing about a computer is that it can perform any computation. Any computation at all. And all without having to rewire the machine. Today everybody takes this idea for granted, but if you stop and think about it, it's kind of amazing that such a device is possible." - This is so true. It's sad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mankind formalized computation and developed two system for it in 1936 with the seminal papers of [Alonzo Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) on [$\lambda$-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) (who today, June 23rd 2012, would turn 100 years old if not for despicable circumstances leading to his early passing) on what became known as Turing-machines. Both mathematicians were solving the *Entscheidungsproblem*.

Although Church's paper was published slightly earlier, Turing was unaware of it when he developed his ideas, and Turing's approach proved to be more useful for the design of real-world machines. This was because he showed how to design a [Universal Turing Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) that could be programmed to run any computation. This universal machine, with a concrete architecture based on the work of [John von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) is the basic idea behind the machine on which you are reading my answer.

As you noted, computable is defined as "computable on a Turing machine" and all other reasonable models of computation have proven to be equivalent in their power. The belief that all reasonable models of computation are equivalent in what decision problems they can solve is known as the [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis). In its original form, it is almost completely believed by the learned community. In fact [it is not completely clear what it would mean to prove/disprove the Church-Turing thesis](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/88/1037); in a lot of ways it becomes an empirical question.

However, there is still the [extended Church-Turing thesis](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/extended-church-turing-thesis) which asks the slightly more subtle question of: what can be computed *efficiently*?. Many *classical* models, such as $\lambda$-calculus, Turing Machines, tag-based systems, cellular automata, etc are equivalent under the extended thesis as well. However, the recent development of [quantum computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer) casts doubt on the extended thesis. Although most people who work on quantum computers (including me) believe they are more efficient that classical ones, the matter is [subject to scholarly debate](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/can-you-hear-the-shape-of-a-quantum-computer/). Note that in terms of the coarse notion of what is computable (as opposed to *efficiently* computable) quantum computing is still equivalent to Turing's model.

Comment: Turing's 1936 paper, compared to Church's work at the time, was much more compelling in its argument that any numerical function that can be computed algorithmically by a human can be computed by a Turing machine. Church's formalisms did not obviously have that property, and to this day the reduction of other computational systems to Turing machines is vital because of Turing's original analysis of what Turing machines can compute.

Comment: @CarlMummert I definitely agree, but Church's work must be mentioned for completeness. Also, it is not at all insignificant, while most of Theory A is built around TMs, Theory B is much more lambda-calc friendly. So it is also partially a difference of cultures.

Comment: Wait - so you're saying that it _hasn't_ been proven that there is no more powerful computational system? It's merely an _assumption_?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid all _reasonable_ models of computation (reasonable roughly means: at one time only working on finite sections of objects and only doing one of finitely many options) that I am familiar with have been shown equivalent to Turing machines.

Comment: There is the field of [hypercomputing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation) what looks at unreasonable models of computation, though. There have been papers that [claim to prove the Church-Turing thesis](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/105/1037) but read the comments on that answer carefully to get an idea of what people think about 'proving' the thesis.

Comment: Right. So there is _evidence_ that Turing-completeness is a good definition, but no formal _proof_ of this?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid proof is a mathematical notion, if you read the comments I linked then you will see that academics tend to regard the CT-thesis as a scientific hypothesis. It is meaningless to talk about 'formal proof' of a scientific hypothesis, you can only talk about falsification or strength of evidence. When you prove something in math, you are just showing that some definitions entail the CT-Thesis, those definitions then in fact become your model of computation.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid To provide a potentially more straightforward answer to your follow-up question: right, nobody has proven that that there isn't some reasonable model of computation more powerful than a TM. "Assumption" is one word for it; "hypothesis" is another. We could wake up tomorrow and see about a new, better model of computing on CNN. It's unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score -2):

There's a reason it's called a Turing Machine, and it's because it was invented by Alan Turing. He did a 1936 paper on it, establishing these concepts. If you want to know more about Turing Machines, check the paper. It was seriously doubted, before he designed and built one that cracked the Enigma, that this concept could actually work. However the British were pretty desperate and he was a genius, so they trusted him and it paid off massively.

However, when you think about it some more, it's really not that amazing at all. It was known long before Turing that all of mathematics could be reduced to some set of axioms. All you would have to do is give the instruction set the ability to perform these axioms, and off you go.

Comment: Turing did not design or build enigma (although he did design another computer which was never built). Your second paragraph is well made: a lot of the excitement around the time of Turing (and indeed this was the point of his own paper) related to the limits of computation.

Comment: We trusted him? Only up until he was publically proven to be a homosexual, then we killed him for it. Also it's been proven that there are a set of problems that can be stated within any axiomatic framework that can never be proven with those axioms.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I know. However, the job of the TM is not to compute *everything*, but only to compute what can be computed. Your statement only says that there are some computations which cannot be proven to be correct. That does not mean that they cannot be done.

Comment: @Marcin: I did not, ever, imply that Turing designed or built the Enigma. I said that he played a critical role in the machine which *cracked* the Enigma.

Comment: This answer is __wrong__. Turing did not design a TM to crack the enigma, he helped design the [Bombe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) which was a specialized machine for attacking the Enigma cipher and not universal. Further, it was not known that mathematics could be reduced to some set of axioms. In fact in 1931 Godel proved the opposite and it is on the ideas of this proof that Turing's work was based.

Even the opening comment about reading Turing's original paper is misleading. Although the paper is great, if you just want to learn the basics a modern textbooks like Sipser is better.